# model method is not called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a method that belongs to Generator.rb

**Generator controller**

```
  # GET /generators/new
  def new
    @generator = current_user.generators.build(params[:generator])
  end

  # POST /generators
  # POST /generators.json
  def create    
    @generator = current_user.generators.build(params[:generator])
    @generator.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    @generator.choice = params[:choice]
      if params[:choice] == 'Randomly'
          @generator.random_generate(generator_params)
      elsif params[:choice] == 'Specified ATGC'
          @generator.specified_ATGC(params[:no_A],params[:no_T],params[:no_G],params[:no_C])
      elsif params[:choice] == 'Seating'
          @generator.seating(params[:user_seq])
      end

    @generator.result_choice=params[:result_choice]
    @generator.save
    respond_to do |format|
       if @generator.result_choice == 'Yes'
              format.html { redirect_to(user_generator_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :id => generator.id)) }
       else
              format.html { redirect_to(user_generators_path(@generator) ) }
       end
     end 
  end
```

However when i run rails console, Generator.all , only user_id and generator_id is there. But the Generator variables are all nil. How can i solve this ? Is there something wrong with my Generator controller new ? I do not how to link User with my Generator. And also Generator will link with Result later.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :generators
  has_many :results, :through=>:generators
```

**Generator.rb**

```
class Generator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :result , :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :choice, :primer_length, :random_primer_generated, :generator_id
```

**Result.rb**

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :generator_id,:ncbi_ref_seq,:genome_seq, :genome_sample
   belongs_to :generator
```

Comment: Did you migrate those params into the database?

Comment: yes. they're in my schema

Comment: ```@generator.user_id = current_user.id if current_user``` shouldn't be needed if you create the generator with ```@generator = current_user.generators.build(params[:generator])``` (the ```user_id``` value should be set already). The only activerecord attribute you are visibly modifying apart from ```user_id``` is ```result_choice``` (```choice``` is an instance attribute and so won't be stored). Are you sure that ```params[:result_choice]``` is being sent to the create action?

Comment: well before this @generator.result_choice = params[:result_choice] was sent to my genrator object. But now after i include User association, eveyrthing returns nil.

Comment: why build again in create?

Comment: well i get `undefined method `choice=' for nil:NilClass` if i erase them in create. N if i didn't erase in create, what should i put in new controller ?

Comment: @generator.save!. you don't look if the save actually does works. Maybe there is some validation error?